# Node.js query INSERT callback not working as expected

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Small problem when using POST and adding an INSERT. Works as below, but want to use a callball after the data has been inserted. At the moment the database is being updated. (good) but can't use the callback - I would expect this to be just below the throw error. So you could use result.insertId.  Any thoughts welcome?

```js
router.post('/group/:id', function(req, res) {

 var idToken = req.params.id;
 
 admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then(function(decodedToken) {
         
   var userID = decodedToken.uid;
   var name = encrypt(req.body.group);
  
   getID(userID, function(result){
    
    var ID = result;
    var post  = {ID:ID, name:name};

    db.query('INSERT INTO cu_groups SET ?', post, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error)throw error;

        //*** when I add response here get 502 bad gateway error.
    
    });
 
    res.sendStatus(200);
       
   }); // depends on getID
    
  // admin.auth cat
  }).catch(function(error) {
  res.sendStatus(error);
  }); 
 
});
```

Comment: I am guessing that the database is not connecting in time before the query?  Once the query is processed the response error has already been returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way :

```
router.post('/group/:id', function(req, res) {

        var idToken = req.params.id;
        admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then(function(decodedToken) {

                var userID = decodedToken.uid;
                var name = encrypt(req.body.group);

                getID(userID, function(result){

                    var ID = result;
                    var post  = {ID:ID, name:name};

                    db.query('INSERT INTO cu_groups SET ?', post, function (error, results, fields) {
                        if(error){
                            return res.status(500).send(error);
                        }
                        if(!error && results){
                            return res.status(200).send(results);
                        }

                    });

                }); 

      }).catch(function(error) {
          return res.status(500).send(error);
      });   

  });
```

if you want to use callback then ,create a separate function like :

```
var insertData = function(query,data,callback){
          db.query(query, data, function (error, results, fields) {
               if(error){callback(error,null);}
               if(!error && results){callback(null,results);}
          });
});
```

and call this way inside getID :

```
     getID(userID, function(result){

                var ID = result;
                var post  = {ID:ID, name:name};

                insertData('INSERT INTO cu_groups SET ?', post, function (error,data){
                    if(error){
                        return res.status(500).send(error);
                    }
                    if(data){
                        return res.status(200).send(data);
                    }
                });

            });
```

Comment: I have used the code without the callback and it is returning a 500 error. Although the data is getting saved in the database. I have even hardcoded the variables so all it needs to do is insert the data (which is does) but then returns the error 500? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Working code below many thanks to Saurabh Mistry.  I removed the SET post and added the table fields and values explicity.

```js
router.post('/group/:id', function(req, res) {

 var idToken = req.params.id;
 
 admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then(function(decodedToken) {
         
   var userID = decodedToken.uid;
   var name = encrypt(req.body.group);
  
   getID(userID, function(result){
    
        var ID = result;
   
        // query
     let query = "INSERT INTO cu_groups (ID, name) VALUES('" + ID + "','" + name + "')";
     
     // execute query
     db.query(query,  (error, result) => {
                   
                      
                        if(error){
                           return res.status(500).send(error); 
                        }
                        if(!error && result ){
                            return res.send(result);
                        }
      
     

                    });
    
 
   }); // depends on getID
    
  // admin.auth cat
  }).catch(function(error) {
  return res.status(500).send(error); 
  }); 
 
});
```